# WEB from PHP to Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to understand how the logic of Ruby (ROR) works for web development. I've already tried tutorials of Ruby, but need to see a code of simple web system.

Could you please rewrite the following simple code with PHP, as it's written on ROR? You would help me a lot.

**// HTML/CSS/JS:**

```
<html>
<head>..
<script>
function send(){
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); 
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/send.php', true); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
xmlhttp.send("data=" + $("#test").val() );              

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
           if(xmlhttp.responseText) alert("Done");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type='text' id='test' />
<button onclick='send()'>OK</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**// Send.php**

```
<?php>

$data=$_POST['data'];

if($data=='1')
  echo true;
else
  echo false;

</php>
```

Comment: Ruby on Rails is an extremely productive web application framework written in Ruby. so you need to learn ruby on rails framework unless you cant get the logic behind everything

Comment: You should start by reading a tutorial about Ruby. (btw... `echo true` will output `1` and `echo false` won't output anything).

Comment: @Vishal - Before learning Ruby on Rails, he should really learn the Ruby language. Otherwise it's like saying that you should learn jQuery before vanilla Javascript.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah.. you are right bro.. my mistake.. :)

Comment: Guys, I don't ask about the syntax. I need the logic. If you know, please explain. If you don't know, don't overload the system

Comment: Just write for me this using Ruby, and you will help me a lot.

Comment: just paint my house for me, it will help a lot

Comment: What house are you talking about? This code is not for job, as you see it's too simple. If you don't know, again, don't overload the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of please try [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to see how Ruby on Rails (!= ruby!!) works.

In your case this code would make sense:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'example' => 'example#something'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Your controller:

```
# app/controllers/example_controller.rb
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  def something
    result = { ok: params[:data] == "1" }
    render json: result
  end
end
```

So you could post to `/example` and get a json object with: `{"ok": <true/false>}`

Comment: Where is /example and how it looks like?

Comment: what?

Please read the guide I linked in the answer, I think you don't get the whole routing.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask in other way. Does example_controller work as PHP code, receiving data from Client side and responsing?

Comment: Yes it does. (Dispatching is this called)

Comment: So, to conclude. The server side, in this example, is controller.rb? 
What about routes.rb? It looks like Ajax. Where is it located? In my example Ajax from HTML file sent data to PHP.

Comment: Thanks, understood. 
Last question: If routes are set in routes.rb, do I need Ajax?